# Is Xcode 4.2 available for a MacBook Pro 2.2 with a Core Duo processor?

Tags: hardware-recommendation, xcode

I'm trying to figure out if this computer will be able to run the new Xcode 4.2.

These are the specs:

- MacBook Pro 2.2 15'' Core Duo 2.16GHz (T2600)
- 2 GB RAM

The full specs can be found [here](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/stats/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.16-15-specs.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes.

This rather depends on the OS version than the Mac. Since this Macbook has a 32-bit processor, the latest OS you can install is Snow Leopard. The latest version of Xcode is still made available for Snow Leopard by Apple.

#### [Xcode 4.2 for Lion (Mac App Store)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12)

#### [Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard (direct link)](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_with_ios_5_sdk/xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg)

#### Xcode 3.1.4 for Leopard (latest version that runs on Leopard)

Comment: Will it be able to run it smoothly though?

Comment: @vondip I ran Xcode 4.2 without hassle on a MBP 3.1 (2.2GHz Core2Duo). Therefore, I think you'll be fine. After all Snow Leopard is less hungry for hardware resources than Lion.